# How to configure nuxt to work with requests during server rendering?

Tags: java, nuxt.js

The project has back and front containers hanging in one docker-compose.  [image]

If i run projet locally, make some request from nuxt server render to backend, i get

`Error in created hook (Promise/async): "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.3:80"`

it looks like the nxt is making a request to its own container, and not to the backend container.

Our project use nuxt 2.15.8